# How many ways the set D can be constructed?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, combinations

The following relations hold for four non-empty sets $A,B,C,D$:

1. $ A \cup B \cup C \cup D = A \cap B $
2. $ B \cup C \cup D = B \cap C $
3. $ C \cup D = C  $

   If $A = \{1,2,3,4\} $ then in how many ways can the set $D$ be constructed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(3) tells you that $D\subseteq C$; why?

(2) tells you that $B\cup C\subseteq B\cap C$. It’s always true that $B\cap C\subseteq B\cup C$, so $B\cup C=B\cap C$. This tells you that $B\subseteq B\cap C$, and it’s always true that $B\cap C\subseteq B$, so $B=B\cap C$, and therefore $B\subseteq C$. Use a similar argument to show that $C\subseteq B$, and conclude that $B=C$, so that $B\cup C=B\cap C=B=C$. Now (2) tells you further that $B\cup D=B$ and hence that $D\subseteq B=C$.

We can use the previous result to reduce (1) to $A\cup B\cup D=A\cap B$. Use the ideas of the previous paragraph to extract information from this. When you’ve done that, you’ll know how $D$ must relate to $A$.

Comment: nice explanation sir

Comment: @monalisa: Thank you.